# How to pass HTTP_AUTHORIZATION to php5-cgi?

Tags: php, apache, http-authentication

I have a virtual server running Ubuntu 12.04 and using php5-cgi. It was auto installed by Plesk 11 and I'm not sure if I can safely replace it with libapache2-mod-php5 or php5-fpm.

HTTP authentication doesn't work on my server and I found out that it works with libapache2-mod-php5 or php5-fpm. I guess that apache doesn't pass the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION properly to the php5-cgi.

Is there any way to enable it or any working workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Place this at the top of your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Even with mod_fastcgi.c (fcgid is not installed) it does not work.

Comment: Did you try without checking for the module, just run those 2 lines?